# how to read different excel files data into Opl cplex data file and execute the model?

Tags: cplex

i am doing a project in scheduling and i have a problem in reading the excel files into Cplex. At present i able to connect to one excel file through SheetConnection and Sheetread commands, but in my project i am dealing with 150 excel files- where 50 of them contains 5jobs and their processing times of machines data, another 50 files contains data of 100jobs and their processing times and the rest are of 150 jobs and their corresponding processing time on machines data. Can anyone help me how to read different excel files data into Opl cplex data file and execute the model?

I have 150 different excel files not different sheets in one excel file.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are trying to solve 150 different instances of the same problem. You will need to write some code (e.g. in OPL script) to create your model with the relevant data from each spreadsheet.

Comment: Mr.Tim, yes i am dealing with different instances of the same problem. can you please provide a clear explanation with a example which clarifies my question. how should i write that script in my model and how to write multiple files in my dat file

Answer (score 1):

The same question was asked [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/522821/how-to-read-different-excel-files-data-into-opl-cp.html). I copy my answer from there:

From the user manual [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_datasources_spreadsheet_connect.html):

> It is possible in OPL to connect to several spreadsheets within the
>   same model.

So you can have multiple SheetConnection statements, one for each sheet:

```
SheetConnection sheet1("sheet1.xls");
SheetConnection sheet2("sheet2.xls");
...
```